# Отправка email-сообщений при помощи C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

Как при помощи C# отправить pdf себе на почту?
У меня получилось найти только это(скрин снизу), но хотелось бы что-то актуальное.
[image: скрин]

Comment: ну вы дальше то почитайте, [что там написано](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sskFV.png)

Comment: [#](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

Comment: При генерации документации атрибут obsolete притянули из моно. Реально никакой официальной отметки об устарении там нет, можете спокойно пользоваться. Я постил им об этом баг,  его уже два года чинят. https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2986

Comment: @tym32167 там важно кто именно эти we :)